# How to create n proxies with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, proxy

I am looking to create many HTTP proxies. I think AWS EC2 might be a good idea? I was thinking that perhaps I could create an EC2 (Ubuntu Server 18.04) t3.nano instance for each proxy that I want. Then, I follow a guide such as https://www.tecmint.com/install-squid-in-ubuntu/, I do that for each instance. However, I'm not sure if that guide is the best way to do it, and I would like to setup usernames and passwords for each proxy and I don't think that shows how to do that.

I would like to use probably up to 500 proxies at a time, so obviously I will need to create a script to generate the EC2 instances, then another script to set them all up to be proxies. Then finally a script that will output a list of IP:Port:Username:Proxy into a text file.

I have installed `aws-shell` which I think is what I need to use to launch the instances. I think to create one I should use something like this

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-xxxxxxxx --count 1 --instance-type t3.nano --key-name MyKeyPair --security-group-ids sg-903004f8 --subnet-id subnet-6e7f829e
```

But I don't understand the information it is asking me for, such as ami, sg-xxx and subnet. I assume I should replace the 1 after count with how many I want to make.

And then how would I run the script to set them all to be proxy servers? And output the proxy data?

Sorry if this question is a bit confusing, it's just that I am quite confused and would really appreciate some guidance.

By the way, I picked t3.nano because they have high network speeds but low memory.

I just assumed AWS would be the best way, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You'll quickly hit the limit on the number of instances that AWS will let you spin up. What are you _really_ trying to do? (although, TBH, there aren't a lot of reasons that you'd need that many proxies, and most of them aren't the sort of thing that people here will help you to do).

Comment: @guest How else can I do it then? What is the max? It's nothing illegal lol don't worry, nothing to do with DDOS or whatever

Comment: about limits https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-resource-limits.html

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

there is free service to create unlimited Amazon AWS proxy servers.
https://createproxy.com

Your problem will be only amount of EC2 servers amazon let you create, by default it is I think 10, but you can increase this limit by contacting AWS support team.. But have no idea if they allow you to create 500 servers.

But If not, you will need more Amazon AWS accounts or you can create 100 proxy servers on Amazon AWS, 100 on Google Cloud, 100 on digital ocean, 100 on Linode and 100 on Vultr - so this is main reason why use some tool like https://createproxy.com.

Please note that you can always select whatever instance (even t3.nano) and datacenter location.

CreateProxy.com allow you also call for creating/deleting your proxies by API. https://createproxy.com/api/

Answer (score 0):

Using a Proxy on Amazon EC2 Instances. If you configure a proxy on an Amazon EC2 instance launched with an attached IAM role, ensure that you exempt the address used to access the instance metadata. To do this, set the NO_PROXY environment variable to the IP address of the instance metadata service, 169.254.169.254.

Here is official documentation which will guide you better

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-proxy.html

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I think you have misunderstood the question. I don't want to access AWS via a proxy, I want to use AWS to generate proxies.